# Modify post ID to be incremental, ignoring posts with a custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to modify post ids to be incremental while ignoring posts that have a custom field titled "foldout". I can't seem to get it work, and I'm not getting any php errors. I have this at the end of my functions.php file

```
function updateNumbers() {
/* numbering the published posts: preparation: create an array with the ID in sequence of publication date, /
/ save the number in custom field 'incr_number' of post with ID /
/ to show in post (within the loop) use <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'incr_number',true); ?>
/ alchymyth 2010 */
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'post' AND wpostmeta.meta_key != 'foldout'  ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$counts = 5 ;
if ($pageposts):
foreach ($pageposts as $post):
setup_postdata($post);
$counts++;
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts, true);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'incr_number', $counts);
endforeach;
endif;
}
add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'deleted_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'edit_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the query string mentioned here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#Query_based_on_Custom_Field_and_Category

I can get this to work:

```
$querystr =    "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
                FROM $wpdb->posts 
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' ";
```

but not this:

```
$querystr =   "SELECT wposts.* 
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
                WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
                AND wpostmeta.meta_key != 'foldout' 
                AND wposts.post_type = 'post' ";
```

Which I modified from the "Query based on Custom Field and Sorted by Value" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick, found a similar answer by googling more.

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT ID, post_title, post_content FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE not exists ( SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE ($wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID) AND meta_key = 'foldout')
    AND (post_status = 'publish')
    AND (post_type = 'post')
";
```